# ARIMA Model Problems

Tags: self-study, forecasting, arima

[image: ARIMA Model Problems]

Hi! Can anyone help me out with this question I found on my practice paper?

For part a) I think it is a ARMA (1,1) process? is that correct? and how do I calculate the mean of the ARMA model? is it the same as AR model? If it is then E(yt) - 5/ (1-0.30) = 7.14?

For part b) I identified as the AR(4). Is that correct?

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph or screenshot (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). When you retype the question,
add the `[self-study]` tag & read 
[its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. 
We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: ok sure thank you! done!

Comment: Thank you for reposting the question! (Next time, best to just edit this one. I have flagged this question for deletion, since we don't need it any more.)